# Make Tmux export DISPLAY on reattachment

Tags: bash, tmux

I'm working on an SSH-connection with Tmux version 2.6, and having some problems with the bash environment `DISPLAY` not being equal to the Tmux `DISPLAY` - which makes it impossible to display anything.

After some searching, it seemed that running

```
export DISPLAY="`tmux show-env | sed -n 's/^DISPLAY=//p'`"
```

were the solution, however sometimes after reattachment, the Tmux `DISPLAY` are reset into something else than what bash is using, and it breaks again.

I tried to run

```
set-hook -g client-attached 'run-shell update_display.sh'
```

in the .tmux.conf file with `update_display.sh` just containing the above export-command, however this didn't do anything. 
For testing, I tried to run

```
run-shell "export DISPLAY='testing'"
```

again in the .tmux.conf file, and this didn't even change the `DISPLAY`.

Am I missing something obvious here? Are Tmux not allowed to export like this, or what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Commands run with run-shell can't affect the global environment in tmux (unless you run "tmux setenv"), so your run-shell commands won't work.

If you want to set tmux's DISPLAY explicitly, used "tmux setenv DISPLAY ..." rather than 'run-shell "export DISPLAY ..."'.

Most likely the reason it is changing is because it is in update-environment (it is by default) and you are attaching from a terminal with a new DISPLAY (or without DISPLAY set). But that is the whole point... if that didn't happen, then running "tmux setenv" from the shell inside tmux wouldn't do anything meaningful.